# Error inflating class fragment on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my app with 2 fragments, everything works fine, but am getting a 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp2.app/com.myapp2.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment`when I have fragment2 on portrait screen an change it to landscape...

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    f1 = (FragmentListView) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    if(f1 != null)
        f1.setCommunicator(this);

}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0.0dp"
android:paddingRight="0.0dp"
android:paddingTop="0.0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0.0dp"
tools:context="com.myapp2.app.MainActivity">
<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My content_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0.0pt"
android:paddingRight="0.0pt"
android:paddingTop="0.0pt"
android:paddingBottom="0.0pt"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:name="com.myapp2.app.FragmentListView"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My content_main.xml(large):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0.0pt"
android:paddingLeft="0.0pt"
android:paddingRight="0.0pt"
android:paddingTop="0.0pt"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.myapp2.app.FragmentListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="com.myapp2.app.FragmentDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="2" />
```

I've read I have to have a FragmentLayout if I want to change fragments at runtime, but if I change my @id/fragment to a FragmentLayout my app doesn't even start...

Does someone know why it's happening?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure your activity layout file name is activity_main.xml. And MainActivity is  declared in Manifest file.

Comment: Main activity is declared in Manifest file, and activity layout fine name is activity_main.xml. My app works, it just crashes when I change screen orientation with fragment2 visible.